Pyomo can't find any solution to my problem
A solar plant is supplying power to three water pumps, and other appliances and I want to find when should I run my water pumps to make the most of the solar plant (since its production through days is not constant).
I tried to implement such an optimization problem on Pyomo, but he provides me 0 solution, and it seems like he is taking only one out of my three constraints, which is quite surprising since it doesn't appear to be a very complex problem.
My modelisation follows these rules :
•   power_m_pyomo contains the average yield power of the solar panel per month (indexed by m) and per hour between 8 and 17 (indexed by Id),
•   base_demand contains the electricity demand of the appliances, which is equals to 90 kW every hour between 8 and 17,
•   model.P contains the number of water pumps that should be running each hour. So it's a positive integer smaller or equal to 3. I only need 9 "equivalent hour of water pump running per day", which means that the sum of model.P[i] should be equal to 9.
The objective function is the average of the ratio between the excess power (that can be negative if the supply power is higher than the demand) over the supply power. It's not the best option for my case, but I'm using this one because it's linear (I'd rather use the sum of the exact excess power required per year, but it requires the use of the max function).
My code is :
# Importation of the supplied power
df = pd.read_csv('test_power.csv', header=0, names=["Hour", "Power [kW]"])
power_supplied = df['Power [kW]'].tolist()

# Creation of the average monthly yield power 
power_m = monthly_profile_creation(power_supplied)

# Conversion of the power supplied into something that can be used by Pyomo
power_m_pyomo = {}
for m in range(1,13):
    for h in range(8, 18):
        power_m_pyomo[(m,h)] = power_m[m][h]
    

# Creation of the model (now empty)
model = pyomo.ConcreteModel()

# Creation of index for the peak demand
model.M = pyomo.Set(initialize = range(1, 13))
model.Id = pyomo.Set(initialize = range(8, 18))

# Parameters 
base_demand = list_to_dico([90]*10, 8)
model.base_demand = pyomo.Param(model.Id, initialize=base_demand)
model.power_supplied = pyomo.Param(model.M, model.Id, initialize=power_m_pyomo)

# Variables
model.P = pyomo.Var(model.Id, domain=pyomo.Integers)

# Objective function

def objective_func(model):
    power_stored = 0
    for m in model.M:
        for i in model.Id:
            power_stored_hourly = model.base_demand[i] + 24*model.P[i] - model.power_supplied[m,i]
            power_stored += power_stored_hourly/model.power_supplied[m,i]     
    return power_stored/(len(model.M)*(len(model.Id)))
model.objective = pyomo.Objective(rule = objective_func, sense=pyomo.minimize)

# Constraints

def constraint_pump_1(model, i):
    return model.P[i] <= 3
model.constraint_pump_1 = pyomo.Constraint(model.Id, rule=constraint_pump_1)

def constraint_pump_2(model):
    return sum([model.P[i] for i in model.Id]) == 9
model.constraint_pump_2 = pyomo.Constraint(rule=constraint_pump_2)

def constraint_pump_3(model, i):
    return model.P[i] >= 0
model.constraint_pump_3 = pyomo.Constraint(model.Id, rule=constraint_pump_3)

solver = pyomo.SolverFactory("cbc")
results = solver.solve(model, keepfiles=False, logfile="solve.log", tee=True)
print(results)

By the way, when I'm pprint my model, it shows that the three constraints has been declared...
Can someone help me ?
The other parts of the code (not important to understand the model but whatever) is :
import pyomo.environ as pyomo
import pandas as pd

def monthly_profile_creation(power):
    """
    Create the average monthly yield power of the system.

    Parameters
    ----------
    power : list of 8760 numbers
        Contains the hourly yield power.

    Return
    ------
    power_m : dictionary of 12 indices
        Contains the average yield power of the system for each month.

    """
    # power_d is a dictionary indexed by the number of days, and containing
    # the hourly yield power of the system.
    power_d = {}
    for d in range(365):
        power_per_day = []
        for h in range(24):
            power_per_day.append(power[h+d*24])
        power_d[d] = power_per_day
    
    power_m = {}
    months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    actual_day = 0
    for m in range(len(months)):
        list_power_one_month = []
        for d in range(months[m]):
            list_power_one_month.append(power_d[actual_day])
            actual_day += 1
        power_m[m+1] = [sum(x)/months[m] for x in zip(*list_power_one_month)]
    
    return power_m

def list_to_dico(input_list, starting_index):
    """
    To convert a list into a dictionary, indexed by integers from starting_index (for Pyomo).

    Parameters
    ----------
    input_list : list
        The list that will be converted.
        
    starting_index : int.
        The starting value for indexes

    Returns
    -------
    dico : dictionary
        Dictionary indexed by integers from starting_index containing the list values.

    """
    dico = {}
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        dico[i+starting_index] = input_list[i]
    return dico


Your model looks "OK" and without more details about what isn't working, it is tough to give good advice.  That said, there are probably a few things to improve.
First, as general advice, you are likely to get better help on this site if your model is a self-contained working example, so no missing .csv files, etc.  It is usually pretty easy to gin up some small fake data to represent the issue as I've done below.
A simplification:  In your model, the solar energy and the "other demands" are a given and don't need to be part of the model.  All you need to worry about is how to manage the power_available as I show below.  So before you do any modeling, just compute that on the side.
Your constraints for the pump running are correct.
There are a couple ideas for a good objective here, and there are a couple not-so-good ones...

Computing the average is useless because it will be the same regardless of choices of when the pump runs...the total aggregate available power - total of all pump running / number of periods is constant
Computing the total excess power required can be done without the max function by means of a positive real variable and a constraint.

Code
import pyomo.environ as pyo

hours = list(range(8, 18))
power_avail = [4.0, 4.0, 6.2, 5.8, 8.7, 7.8, 5.2, 4.1, 3.0, 6.2]
power_avail_dict = dict(zip(hours, power_avail))



# Creation of the model (now empty)
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# Creation of index for the peak demand
# model.M = pyo.Set(initialize = range(1, 13))
model.Id = pyo.Set(initialize = hours)

# Parameters 
# base_demand = list_to_dico([90]*10, 8)
# model.base_demand = pyo.Param(model.Id, initialize=base_demand)
# model.power_supplied = pyo.Param(model.M, model.Id, initialize=power_m_pyo)
model.power_avail = pyo.Param(model.Id, initialize=power_avail_dict)
model.pump_power = pyo.Param(initialize=4.5, doc='power required by pump per hour')

# Variables
model.P = pyo.Var(model.Id, domain=pyo.Integers)
model.excess_power = pyo.Var(model.Id, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, doc='the extra power required in period i')

# Objective function

# minimize the total excess power reqd.
model.objective = pyo.Objective(expr= sum(model.excess_power[i] for i in model.Id))

# Constraints

def constraint_pump_1(model, i):
    return model.P[i] <= 3
model.constraint_pump_1 = pyo.Constraint(model.Id, rule=constraint_pump_1)

def constraint_pump_2(model):
    return sum([model.P[i] for i in model.Id]) == 9
model.constraint_pump_2 = pyo.Constraint(rule=constraint_pump_2)

def constraint_pump_3(model, i):
    return model.P[i] >= 0
model.constraint_pump_3 = pyo.Constraint(model.Id, rule=constraint_pump_3)

def constraint_excess_power(model, i):
    return model.excess_power[i] >=  model.pump_power * model.P[i] - model.power_avail[i]
model.constraint_excess_power = pyo.Constraint(model.Id, rule=constraint_excess_power)

solver = pyo.SolverFactory("cbc")
results = solver.solve(model, keepfiles=False, logfile="solve.log", tee=True)
print(results)

model.P.display()

for idx in model.Id:
    print(f'excess power reqd in period {idx}:  {pyo.value(model.excess_power[idx]) :0.2f}')

Output
Objective value:                1.20000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               13
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01


Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 1.2
  Upper bound: 1.2
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 11
  Number of variables: 20
  Number of binary variables: 0
  Number of integer variables: 10
  Number of nonzeros: 10
  Sense: minimize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.0
  Wallclock time: 0.01
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 13
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.013698101043701172
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

P : Size=10, Index=Id
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      8 :  None :  -0.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
      9 :  None :   1.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
     10 :  None :   1.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
     11 :  None :   1.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
     12 :  None :   2.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
     13 :  None :   1.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
     14 :  None :   1.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
     15 :  None :   1.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
     16 :  None :  -0.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
     17 :  None :   1.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
excess power reqd in period 8:  0.00
excess power reqd in period 9:  0.50
excess power reqd in period 10:  0.00
excess power reqd in period 11:  0.00
excess power reqd in period 12:  0.30
excess power reqd in period 13:  0.00
excess power reqd in period 14:  0.00
excess power reqd in period 15:  0.40
excess power reqd in period 16:  0.00
excess power reqd in period 17:  0.00
[Finished in 278ms]

